# AspectJ: Подключение аспектов

Tags: spring, aop

Есть 2 проекта:

- Тестовый проект "А" (содержащий, к примеру, простой класс с методом `main` c выводом сообщения "*It's A project*");
- Проект "B" содержащий аспекты (*.aj) для обработки вывода сообщения в консоль (к примеру, вывод сообщения "*It's aspect from B project*" перед каждым выводом сообщений в консоль в проекте "А"), + дополнительные классы.

Проекты "А" и "B" основаны на [Spring Framework](https://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/). Проект "B" содержит аспекты, которые используют на данный момент [неподдерживаемую в Spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-instantiation-models) модель `percflow`.

Могу ли я при помощи [компилятора `AspectJ`](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/antTasks-iajc.html) скомпилировать аспекы без использования проекта "A" (а значит и без `compile-time`/`post-compile` [связывания](http://blog.harmonysoft.tech/2009/08/weaving-with-aspectj.html)) и затем на основе проекта "B" собрать jar-файл, который смогу подключить к проекту "A" для дальнейшего использования?

То есть на стадии сборки jar-файла проекту "B" ничего неизвестно о проекте "A".

Вероятно необходимо будет использовать `load-time` связывание. Как именно нужно сконфигурировать Spring для автоматического подхватывания аспектов из jar-файла проекта "B" при его подключении к проекту "A"?

Спасибо.